# How can I display the lowest price from 30 days on my WIX Page?

Tags: velo

How can I display the lowest price from 30 days on my WIX Page? Is it possible to make that using any App or something? Or have I use Velo API?

I tried to search and code by VELO but with 0 progress, could someone help me?